# Transparent layer rendering in the Blender Render Settings

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, render-layers

How can I get the transparent layers in the Blender Render (Not Cycles Render) settings?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In render settings **Shading** -> **Alpha**:

[image]